# Determining the position of a camera based on a trapezoid

Tags: math, image-processing

I have a camera for which I know every parameter: field of view, etc... (I can basically construct it's frustum).
With that camera, I capture a trapezoid every frame like so:

[image]
[image]

My question would be, knowing these parameters, what would be the best way to determine the **position** and **orientation** of the camera?

Comment: Are you looking for [homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision))?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Not entirely sure... I basically want to map 4 2-dimensional coordinates (in window space, like let's say (200, 100), (100, 300), ...) to a 3D position and 2D orientation vector.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Something that I should've probably specified is that I'm using only one camera, and I would like to extract all that information from only one image.

Comment: If you assume your 2D plane is in fact a 3D plane lying on a very specific Z (e.g. z=0) then its a homography! Make a fake 3D plane that you want to correct to.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think it is then :) Are there any particular algorithms / implementations I could use / look into for this case specifically?